# Restrict user attribute while expose the user via graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

The current requirement is exposing some user attributes via graph API.

Ex : [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/%7Bid%7D)

It should return only a few attributes. It can be filtered at the query level.  This query executed by the clients. Don't want to expose all user attributes to them.
what is the solution to control user attributes at the azure level

Thanks
Murali

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, we cannot restrict the user attributes from the azure level for ms graph. Please raise the [user's voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback).

In MS Graph you can use select statement for returning only a few selected attributes.

**For Example:**

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/userid?$select=displayName,givenName
```

Comment: is it possible with claim policy?

Comment: can you please explain your exact scenario where you want to use the claim policy?